# background image url django variable not working

Tags: css, django

I'm setting my css using variables. all colors are working but the background-url isn't

```
background-image: url( {{ custom_colors.comapny_logo }} );
```

I also tried

```
background-image: url( '{{ custom_colors.comapny_logo }}' );
```

How do I properly set the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have misspelled company. Try:

```
background-image: url( '{{ custom_colors.company_logo }}' );
```

If that doesn't work, then update your question with the rendered HTML as well as the template.

Comment: embarrassing, thanks